# Streaming Audio via MEAN Stack?

Tags: angularjs, audio-streaming, meanjs

I'm interested in streaming a looping ambient track on my website.  This would be similar to sites like Coffitivity, wherein a user clicks a button and gets to hear coffee shop background noise playing on a loop:

[image]

Using the MEAN stack, what are some ways to stream audio like this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but it doesn't really have anything to do with your stack.  Serve a simple static audio file to an `<audio>` tag on your page.